# Flex capture all mouse clicks on application

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, actionscript

I want to capture every mouse event and I tried to add event listeners to FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication. However there are some cases (like Flex's Menu class) when the clicks aren't captured - probably somewhere the event propagation is stopped. For example in SystemManager.as I found this:

```
 addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseEventHandler, true, 1000);
```

...which seems to override my listener. Also I tried to add Listeners with priority int.MAX_VALUE but with no success.

So my question is - how can I capture all mouse clicks, without worrying about my events being stopped somewhere? Maybe some javascript hack? Or maybe to add the event listeners somewhere where there is no chance for them to be canceled? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the event handler to stage with capture:

```
systemManager.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseEventHandler, true, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: I already tried that. It seems that the events are captured somewhere and then redispatched and that's why it's not working. I tried attaching the handlers to systemManager, to systemManager.stage, with and without priority and capture, and nothing seems to do the trick.

Comment: It might have something to do with focus leaving on an element that was removed from the Displaylist. I found this [link](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/900/1/Keyboard-events-on-stage-are-not-working-why/Page1.html) that describes similar functionality for Keyboard Event handling:

Comment: Nope, not helping. Still can't capture all events. I am searching for a more general solution, not to handle everything case by case - I just gave the Menu as an example.

Comment: Does it work if you addEventListener both with capture and without? Some events participate only in some parts of the capture-targeting-bubbling phase.